# press radio button get two boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to have it so when you press this button `<input type="radio" name="reise" value="reise">Tur/retur` another box named "avreise"appears on the same page:

[image]

Here is my code for the box. I want to show up when you press the button:

```
print("<script src='validering.js'></script>");
print("<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>");
    print("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>");
    print("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>");
    print("<script>$(document).ready(function() { $('#neste_levering').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });});</script>");
    print("Avreise <input type='text' Value='Klikk for å velge dato' name='neste_levering' id='neste_levering' required></br>");
    print("</select></br>");
    print("<input type='reset' value='Nullstill' id='nullstill' name='nullstill' ></br>");
    print("</form>");

    @$leveringsfrist=$_POST["neste_levering"];

    $dato=date("d-m-Y");

    if ($leveringsfrist) 
    {

    if (!$leveringsfrist) {
    $lovligStudent=false;
    print ("Alt må fylles ut");
    return $lovligStudent;} 

        else { 
    $sqlResultat=mysqli_query($db, $sqlSetning) or die ("Ikke mulig å hente data fra databasen");


    $sqlSetning = "INSERT INTO student VALUES('$leveringsfrist');";
    mysqli_query($db, $sqlSetning) or die ("Kan ikke legge til data i databasen");   
    }
    ?>
    print ("Følgende er registrert i databasen: $brukernavn <br> Navn: $fornavn <br> Etternavn: $etternavn <br> Klassekode: $klassekode <br> avreise: $avreise <br> Bilde: $bildenr");}
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show a textbox when you click the tux/retux radio button.

This can be done in simple way like this. Fox Example

Html:

```
<input type=radio name=cool class=cool value=cool>cool<br>
<input type=radio name=cool class=cool value=Gool>Gool<br>
<input type=text id=fool style="display:none">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.cool').click(function(){
var a=$(this).val();
if(a=="cool")
$('#fool').show();
else
$('#fool').hide();
});
});
```

By clicking the radio button i am checking the value of the radio button if its cool(in your case tur/retux) i am displaying the #fool textbox if not i am hiding the #fool textbox.

If you want another textbox for the click of en vei radio button you can create an another text box and use this same procedure.(in else hide the #fool and display the new one).

This hide() and show() can be used for div tags also(if you want to include text infront of textbox).

Include it in your program as you wish. I hope i helped..

Comment: the avreise box is a calendar that i need, the calendar is in the php code, is there a way to implement it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<input type="radio" name="reise" value="reise" id="radio1">Tur/ Avreise
<input type="radio" name="reise" value="en vei" id="radio2">En vei

Avreise 
<input type='text' Value='Klikk for å velge dato' name='neste_levering' id='neste_levering' required>

<input type='reset' value='Nullstill' id='nullstill' name='nullstill' >

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#neste_levering").hide();

    $("#radio1").click(function(){
        $("#neste_levering").show();
    });
    $("#radio2").click(function(){
        $("#neste_levering").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the avreise box is a calendar that i need, the calendar is in the php code, is there a way to implement it in your code?

Comment: is like datepicker?